# use numeric variable as str & increment it

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to change the value of str used in ajax (str is the string inputted in the html form) part by giving it a variable value, so that by clicking on a button that changes the variable value, the loaded data row in mySQL changes. But it doesn't work. What can I do for this ?
(the ajax works, it's just that the button click doesn't change anything)

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var Pokemon_ID = 0

    function changePokemon(str) {
    
    document.getElementById("right-btn").onclick = function() {
        Pokemon_ID++;
        str = Pokemon_ID
    }
    
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_id.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}   
</script>    
</head>
    
<body>   
    <form>
        First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="changePokemon(this.value)">
    </form>
    <div id="txtHint"></div>
    <a id="right-btn" onclick="changePokemon(str)"></a>

</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: What is `str`? You’re using `onclick="changePokemon(str)"` without any mention of what `str` is.

Comment: `Pokemon_ID++` should have a ; on the end...

Comment: @Xufox str is the string inputted in the html form input

Comment: You have two onclick events one in the onclick handler and one on the button. Remove the line document.getElementById("right-btn").onclick line from the changePokemon function and leave it's contents. Are you trying to pass the input value to the function as str?

Comment: @iSZ thanks for your help, I'm trying to pass the variable Pokemon_ID to the function as str, to be able to change the str input value not only by entering it in the html form text input but also with the button

Comment: @Nas If `str` was anything, it would’ve been defined somewhere. All we can see is that `str` is used as an argument of `changePokemon`. Outside of that, it’s not defined. Haven’t you seen a `ReferenceError` that `str` wasn’t defined in the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12` to open them)?

Comment: Code wise it must be improved .lot of mistakes there

Comment: @Nas because the str variable only exists within the scope of the function you can't pass it as an argument in your call to changePokemon(str). You need to define it outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this out and confirm if it works. I had tried to correct the code according to my understanding of your requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script>    

function changePokemon() {
  let str = document.getElementById("inpStr").value;  
  let tempStr=parseInt(str)+1;

  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","get_id.php?q="+tempStr,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
First name: <input type="text" id="inpStr" onkeyup="changePokemon()">
</form>
<div id="txtHint"></div>

<a id="right-btn" onclick="changePokemon()"></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's exactly want I want to do but I don't know why it still doesn't increment the value when the button is clicked @kanwal019

Comment: Could you explain your requirement in detail ?

Comment: Use `<input type="number">`. It will increment/decrement your input value on key up/down respectively.

Comment: And you need to send the incremented value of the input to your php on the click of the button ?

Comment: yes exactly, because the input type="number" isn't taken in count when I click the up & down keys @kanwal019

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML codes to

```
<form>
    First name:
    <input type="text">
</form>
<div id="txtHint"></div>

<a id="right-btn" onclick="changePokemon(++ Pokemon_ID)">Go</a>
```

I dont know what does your `changePokeMon()` function do, but change your script to

```
    var Pokemon_ID = 0

    function changePokemon(str) {

        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_id.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```